# Как выполнить метод в определенное время?

Tags: c#

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как на C# можно выполнить метод в определенное время? Например, каждый день в 14.00 он должен выполняться.

Comment: А программа всегда запущена?=)

Comment: Ага

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Самый простой и незамысловатый способ - сделать таймер, срабатывающий один раз в минуту и проверяющий время. Как только совпадение - вызываем. =)

```
if ((Hour == System.DateTime.Now.Hour) &&
    (Minute == System.DateTime.Now.Minute))
{
   Nya();
}
```

Вызывать чаще смысла особого, думаю, нет.

Comment: Спасибо вам! Главное, что просто и надежно.

Comment: что то не могу понять как Hour и Minute установить без даты

Comment: Hour = 14; Minute = 00; Так? =D

Comment: Вот так короч сделал :)
<code>
            while (true)
            {
                int Hour = 23;
                int Minute = 42;
                int Seconds = 00;
                if ((Hour == System.DateTime.Now.Hour) && (Minute == System.DateTime.Now.Minute) && (Seconds == System.DateTime.Now.Second))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Проверка");
                }
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
            }
</code>

Comment: Ну, инициализацию можно вытащить из цикла - она ж не меняется никогда =) Да и спать потоку 100 мс - не маловато ли? =) 9 проверок из 10 получаются лишними (время не изменяется) =)

Comment: т.е. можно изменить на 999 мс? :)

Comment: Да что мелочиться = можно и на 1000 =D Если нужна точность до секунды.

Answer (score 6):

```
private void SetTimer() {
    timer1.Stop();
    var timeToAlarm = DateTime.Now.Date.AddHours(...).AddMinutes(...);
    if (timeToAlarm < DateTime.Now)
        timeToAlarm.AddDays(1);
    timer1.Interval = (int)(timeToAlarm - DateTime.Now).TotalMilliseconds;
    timer1.Start();
}
```

и таймер будет вызван только в нужный момент.

Comment: Интересно =) Тока после первого срабатывания придётся перенастроить, но это мелочь.

Comment: Спасибо, скопировал себе код на будущее, просто пока в этих таймерах и событиях не разбираюсь(

Comment: SetTimer() поэтому и отдельный метод, вызывать нужно перед запуском и после срабатывания таймера